# Page content doesn't display to full width in mobile view with RTL attribute

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a blog and I made multilanguage with the use of RTL attribute, when the user change to another language the page content set from LTR to RTL.

In one of the pages, I have toggle tap with content so far everything fine, but when I change to mobile view the toggle tap and its content doesn't display in full width which shows a bad layout as shown below:

[here the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scvtr.png)

and here how it supposed to looks like:

[should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NavSs.png)

and this is the HTML code:

```
    <div class="row d-flex">

        <div class='col pl-md-5 py-md-5 '>

            <div class='row justify-content-start pt-3 pb-3 '>

                <div class='col heading-section ftco-animate '>
                    <h2><?php echo $lang['get-in-touch']; ?></h2>
                    <h2 class='mb-4'></h2>

                    <div class='tabulation-2 mt-4 '>
                        <ul class='nav nav-pills nav-fill d-md-flex d-block'>
                            <li class='nav-item'>
                                <a class='nav-link active py-2' data-toggle='tab'
                                    href='#home4'><?php echo $lang['contact us']; ?></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class='nav-item'>
                                <a class='nav-link py-2 mb-md-0 mb-2' data-toggle='tab'
                                    href='#home2'><?php echo $lang['register']; ?></a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                        <div class='tab-content bg-light rounded mt-2'>

                            <div class='tab-pane container p-0 fade' id='home4'>

                                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method='POST'>
                                    <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $lang['contact us desc']; ?></h5>
                                   
                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                        <input type='text' name='name' class='form-control'
                                            placeholder='<?php echo $lang['name'];?>'>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                        <input type='text' name='email' class='form-control'
                                            placeholder='<?php echo $lang['email'];?>'>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                        <input type='text' name='phone' class='form-control'
                                            placeholder='<?php echo $lang['phone'];?>'>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                        <input type='text' name='subject' class='form-control'
                                            placeholder='<?php echo $lang['title'];?>'>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                        <textarea name='message' id='' cols='30' rows='7' class='form-control'
                                            placeholder='<?php echo $lang['message'];?>'></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                   
                                   
                                        <div class="parentElement">
                                            <input type='submit' name='submit-message'
                                                value='<?php echo $lang['send-m'];?>' class='btn btn-primary btns'>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class='tab-pane container p-0 fade' id='home2'>
                                <p> </p>
                                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method='POST'
                                    class='bg-light p-4 p-md-5 contact-form'>
                                    <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $lang['register desc']; ?></h5>
                                    <br>
                                    

                                </form>
                            </div>



                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is css code:

```
[lang="ar"], [lang="ar"] * {
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right !important;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "Changa", sans-serif;
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.d-flex {
    display: -webkit-box !important;
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;

}
.row {
 
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.col {
  
    flex-basis: 0;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.justify-content-start {
    -webkit-box-pack: start !important;
    -ms-flex-pack: start !important;
    justify-content: flex-start !important;
}
.pb-3, .py-3 {
    padding-bottom: 1rem !important;
}
.pt-3, .py-3 {
    padding-top: 1rem !important;
}
.ftco-animate {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
.col {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: insert your css. need more code

Comment: or give link to site

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov hi, thanks for your replying, I have updated the question .

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no problem with the code you posted. I just wrapped the `<div class="row d-flex">` div with a `container` and wrapped the container with a parent and it did work well. I couldn't reproduce your issue.

Could you please provide more CSS maybe there is a problem with it?

Note that I tested your code with `dir="rtl"` applied to the `<HTML>` tag and I downloaded the RTL bootstrap from the official website. And it didn't show me any problem.

I also applied `dir="rtl"` to the `parent` class and I couldn't see your problem it was working perfectly fine for me.

So in conclusion I think there is something else causing this overflow maybe a different section.

Here is a great article from CSS-TRICKS on how to find body overflow. [Finding/Fixing Unintended Body Overflow](https://css-tricks.com/findingfixing-unintended-body-overflow/)

---

Update

---

I added your CSS and tested it and yep there was nothing wrong for me.

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row d-flex">

      <div class='col pl-md-5 py-md-5 '>

        <div class='row justify-content-start pt-3 pb-3 '>

          <div class='col heading-section ftco-animate '>
            <h2>
              <?php echo $lang['get-in-touch']; ?>
            </h2>
            <h2 class='mb-4'></h2>

            <div class='tabulation-2 mt-4 '>
              <ul class='nav nav-pills nav-fill d-md-flex d-block'>
                <li class='nav-item'>
                  <a class='nav-link active py-2' data-toggle='tab' href='#home4'>
                    <?php echo $lang['contact us']; ?>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class='nav-item'>
                  <a class='nav-link py-2 mb-md-0 mb-2' data-toggle='tab' href='#home2'>
                    <?php echo $lang['register']; ?>
                  </a>
                </li>

              </ul>
              <div class='tab-content bg-light rounded mt-2'>

                <div class='tab-pane container p-0 fade' id='home4'>

                  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method='POST'>
                    <h5 class="card-title">
                      <?php echo $lang['contact us desc']; ?>
                    </h5>

                    <div class='form-group'>
                      <input type='text' name='name' class='form-control' placeholder='<?php echo $lang[' name '];?>'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                      <input type='text' name='email' class='form-control' placeholder='<?php echo $lang[' email '];?>'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                      <input type='text' name='phone' class='form-control' placeholder='<?php echo $lang[' phone '];?>'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                      <input type='text' name='subject' class='form-control' placeholder='<?php echo $lang[' title '];?>'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                      <textarea name='message' id='' cols='30' rows='7' class='form-control' placeholder='<?php echo $lang[' message '];?>'></textarea>
                    </div>


                    <div class="parentElement">
                      <input type='submit' name='submit-message' value='<?php echo $lang[' send-m '];?>' class='btn btn-primary btns'>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </form>
              </div>
              <div class='tab-pane container p-0 fade' id='home2'>
                <p> </p>
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method='POST' class='bg-light p-4 p-md-5 contact-form'>
                  <h5 class="card-title">
                    <?php echo $lang['register desc']; ?>
                  </h5>
                  <br>


                </form>
              </div>



            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### update 2

Hey, there I did check it out and the problem is caused by the `js-fullheight` library. It is causing the `img` to have a side scroll for some reason. On top of that, you should consider using `rtl-bootstrap` to get of margin and padding issues caused by the `dir="rtl`

after that, you should be good to go. Here is the result after removing the `js-fullheight` library, and the `margin-right` *( you should use bootstrap-rtl here )* since it will do that automatically for you.

[image: result]

Comment: thank you for replying. I followed your instruction but still doesn't work for me. you can check the website may will help you more to identify my problem: tiyacademy.com , navtigate to contact us page and display it in mobile view. thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, there I did check it out and the problem is caused by the `js-fullheight` library. It is causing the `img` to have a side scroll for some reason.